# Auto Updating from Git

Tags: git

I want to create a program that runs continuously on background and checks if there is an update in the git repo. If there is it will automatically update on the local.

For example:

I have a project of continuously reading data from 2-3 sensors and send it to thingspeak. Now I have updated the git repo for this project and it now supports more than 3 sensors of different types.

This script should continuously check for an update in the repo and update it on local. If possible it should also look for release versions.

I tried to search and found this:

https://dzone.com/articles/github-continuous-deployment-to-a-raspberry-pi

and

https://www.engineersgarage.com/contributions/automatic-software-update-by-iot-device-over-ftp-protocol-iot-part-44/

Anyone has any idea how to do it or any reference to example/tutorial?

Comment: What's the problem with the sources?

Comment: @M.Rostami Sorry, I did not understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Did you follow the references? https://www.engineersgarage.com/contributions/automatic-software-update-by-iot-device-over-ftp-protocol-iot-part-44/
https://dzone.com/articles/github-continuous-deployment-to-a-raspberry-pi

Comment: It "sounds like" you *may* be able to do what you want with `git` and `cron`. Are you familiar nough with `git` ti write a script to do the updates you want? If so, edit your question to include the `git` code/command sequence, and we can help with the `cron` setup.

Comment: @M.Rostami yes. I read the full document and Created a free server on biz.nf. Ok so you are saying what is the problem using this FTP server as a source, right?
I searched and found that FTP servers are not secure and also I am currently searching for its best alternative or upgrade which is secure.
Then I looked into "Mycroft-open source voice assistant" and they created a skill, core repo on git and were doing automate update through it. I thought I can try and learn this. I am just doing it as a learning process.

Comment: @Seamus I am not that much familiar with it but I know basic add, commit, git-flow init, merge conflict, push and pull just the basics. If you can give reference to an example or tutorial I can try to create on my own.

Comment: *"checks if there is an update in the git repo. If there is it will automatically update on the local."* -> **That is what `git` does.**  This is like saying, "I would like something on my phone to check if my friend is answering his phone, and, if so, call him."  O_O? Just call him.

Comment: @goldilocks so you are saying every sometimes do git fetch or git pull for that repo?

Comment: Yes; use the full repo and branch name (eg. `git pull origin master`).  You could redirect the output to a log file (`git pull origin master &> somefile.txt`; beware `&>` is a bashism); it will just say "Already up to date".

Comment: @goldilocks Thank you. I will try it and will see if I can update it any more or not.